# Helper not showing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

I have the following rails helper :

```
def prefixes_with_tip shops
    capture do 
      shops.each do |s|
        content_tag(:span,class: 'has-tip',title: s.name) do
          concat s.prefix
          Rails.logger.debug "TEST TEST TEST #{s.name} TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST "
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

call :

```
=prefixes_with_tip shop_list
```

When it's called in a view, I can see the traces in the console, but there is no output in the view.

What is wrong with this helper?

(Rails 4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how `concat` is used, try using it **outside** `content_tag`, like this:

```
def prefixes_with_tip shops
  capture do 
    shops.each do |s|
      concat content_tag(:span, s.prefix, class: 'has-tip',title: s.name)
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that the *block* was removed (otherwise `concat` won't work) and added `s.prefix` as the second parameter (which sets the *content* of the *tag*).

Comment: Let's imagine I wanted to iterate again Inside the p tag. How would I do that?

Comment: That is, each item (`s`) should be in a `span` inside a `p`? For example: `<p><span class="has-tip" title="s.name">s.prefix</span></p>`. Some output like that?